# How can I use absolute and relative positioning on images correctly?

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I position images to stack on each other? The first Image is positioned relatively and subsequent images are positioned absolutely. On bigger screen sizes, the images positioned absolutely move leftward and on mobile, they are just over the place depending on screen size. How can I get them to stay on each other whenever they are needed?

This is the JSX code

```
class PizzaBuilder extends Component {
  render (){
 return(
<div>
                   <img className={styles.Pizzapan} src={Pizzapan} alt="pizzapan"/>
                   <div>
                     <div className={styles.Sauce} >
                     <div>
                      <img style={{display: this.state.toggle === "Marinara"?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '100', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}}  src={Marinara} alt="marinara"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                      <img style={{display: this.state.toggle === "Ranchdressing"?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '100', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}} src={Ranchdressing} alt = "ranchdressing"/>
                     </div>
                     <div>
                      <img style={{display: this.state.toggle === "bbqsauce"?"block":null, position:'absolute', zIndex: '100', height: '400px', width: '400px', top:'375px', left: '130px'}} src={Bbqsauce} alt="bbqsauce"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
</div>
)

}

}
```

Corresponding CSS styles

```
.Pizzapan {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

The relative position is set on the image "pizzapan".

Comment: Please update your question with the rendered HTML and not the JSX. It's easier to help when we can see what is in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "position:relative" to the parent div

```css
.mypizza{
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="mypizza" >
```

Comment: I did but its still the same. The images go all around the place.

Comment: I set the relative positioning to both the div and the image and it works now.